# How return multiple exceptions from __init__ method?

Tags: python, exception

I have in `__init__()` of my class 3 connections with external devices. I want to try open them, and return string, or list of strings with information which devices aren't connected properly. Main problem is: this class is called from another program, and `__init__` method must return `None`, not string.

Code:

```
def __init__(self):
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    rm.list_resources()
    self.thermometer = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x164E::0x0DAD::TW00020217::INSTR')

    com = find_com.find_device('USB Serial Port')
    self.voltmeter = serial.Serial(com, baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

    com = find_com.find_device('CH340')
    self.arduino = serial.Serial(com, baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
```

After help from @Carcigenicate comments I tried:

```
class Aparature:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
            rm.list_resources()
            self.thermometer = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x164E::0x0DAD::TW00020217::INSTR')
        except Exception:
            raise Exception('thermometer is not connected properly\n')

        try:
            com = find_com.find_device('USB Serial Port')
            self.voltmeter = serial.Serial(com, baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception('voltmeter is not connected properly\n')

        try:
            com = find_com.find_device('CH340')
            self.arduino = serial.Serial(com, baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception('arduino is not connected properly')

try:
    self.Meters = Aparature()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It prints only first exception but I want to print all occurred.

Comment: If you want to return data, you'll need to do it via a method of the object or something else.

Comment: so I should make method in this class which stores error data and after creating an object call that method?

Comment: It depends on how exactly this code is going to be used. You could also have a factory function/object that creates instances of this class for you, and optionally returns error messages instead of an object if something goes wrong. It's hard to say without more context about the usecase. You could even throw exceptions from inside `__init__` and have the caller catch them.

Comment: `Exception` is a class and when you call it an instance is created and returned (as with most classes). This means they could  be stored in a container like a list instead of being used in a `raise` statement. This should provide a way to "return" more than one of them. You might want to derive your own custom `Exception` subclass to handle the situation.

Comment: Ya, you can't throw multiple exceptions at once. If you have multiple errors, you could gather all the messages into a list, then at the end have something like `if errors: raise Exception(f"Errors: {', '.join(errors)}")`. `Exception` isn't the right exception to use most of the time though. I think `ValueError`, `RuntimeError`, or as martinea suggests, your own `Exception` subclass would be better. Throwing `Exception` makes the catcher's life more difficult.

Comment: Exceptions are intended to signal unrecoverable errors. If you can still attempt to configure the voltmeter even if the thermometer fails, you should simply *remember* that you caught the exception, rather than raising one immediately. As Carcigenicate says, you can later raise a single exception that indicates all the errors that occurred.

Comment: @chepner In my program, if any of  them fails there is no sense runnig the program